# How to compute the divergence of the function $h(x)=Ax$, where $A$ is a matrix and $x$ is a vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

I have to compute the divergence of function h (i.e $div(h)$), where
$$h(x)=Mx \quad \text{where} \quad M\in R_{nxn} \quad \text{and}\quad x \in R^{n}$$
I know this definiton of divergence
$$div(g(z)) = \sum_i^n \frac{d}{dx_i} g_i(z),$$
but I'm not sure how to aplly it here. I tried to write it as
$$h(x)= \Bigg[\begin{matrix} m_{11}x_{1} & ... & m_{1n}x_{n} \\ . & . & . \\m_{n1}x_{n} & ... & m_{nn}x_{n}\end{matrix} \Bigg]=\Bigg[\begin{matrix} \sum_i^n m_{1i}x_{i} \\ ... \\  \sum_i^n m_{ni}x_{i} \end{matrix}\Bigg]. $$
But I don't know what to do next. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Does this help you? https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Your work is good, you just need to continue it. The $j$-th row is:
$$h_j=\sum_{i}m_{ji}x_i$$
And you need to differentiate it with respect to $x_j$. Notice that $m_{ji}$ is just a constant, so:
$$\frac{\partial h_j}{\partial x_j}=\sum_{i}m_{ji}\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}$$
Can you calculate $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}$?

Comment: So I need to take derivative with respect to x_1 for the first row, ..., w/ respect to x_n for the n-th row,etc? And then I get the sum m_11+m_22+...+m_nn? I am not sure if I understand it well.

Comment: @user13696679 That's it, the answer is the trace of $M$. The whole computation looks like this in Einstein convention (with extra details): $h_i=M_{ij}x_j$, so $\text{div}(h)=\partial_ih_i=\partial_iM_{ij}x_j=M_{ij}\partial_ix_j=M_{ij}\delta_{ij}=M_{ii}=\text{Tr}(M)$